# Why is my texture not showing up in 3D view?

Tags: texturing, uv

[image]

I've tried every display mode possible and nothing happens. What do? Here's the blend:
[image]

Comment: This worked only in Blender Render mode in the previous versions and it's not included in 2.8 or newer versions. You have to create a material for the object and assign the texture to it in the Shader Editor.

Comment: 1. 3D view mode is juts going to show geometry
2. You have incorrectly connected the texture in shading

Comment: In the picture you only have the solid mode active, in this mode there won't be any texture shown, use material preview or render mode instead. That aside, i downloaded your file and sadly the texture in question was not included. But looking at the materials that were in the scene, i found that neither of them had any node, not even an output node. So those could be disregarded anyway. I'd make a new material and connect the texture as an image texture with the wanted image selected in it.

Answer (score 0):

To enable textures in object mode (can skip if you're working in Eevvee Rendered mode or LookDev) :

[image: enable texture in object mode]

To enable the texture to appear, click use nodes, then click on the little circle next to the color to select your open image:

[image: add texture to material]

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was being in *Solid* shading mode, as suggested in the comments above.

To change it to *Rendered* either click the viewport shading icons at the top right of the 3D Viewport or press <kbd>Z</kbd> in the 3D viewport and select *Rendered* from the pie menu.